# ListView link to formview

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

I'm using a ListView and a FormView in different pages.

What I need is to be able to click on one of the records and show the FormView with that record to update it. Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ListView you will need to make the field you want to click on a HyperLink field. The `NavigateUrl` will then contain a link to the page you need to go to, and also pass a value using the QueryString to the page for example `?Id={value}`.

The recieving page will then retrieve the value from the QueryString and you will need to recreate the datasource, and retrieve the data only for the value passed in the QueryString and rebind the FormView

**In response to the comment**

From code behind you can retrieve the QueryString in your load method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Request.QueryString[{VariableName]))
         {
              string someVariable = this.Request.QueryString[{VariableName}];
         }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can do this in the HTML if your using a `SqlDataSource` provider or similiar in the parameters collection for the select statement.

```
<asp:sqldatasource id="test" runat="server">
    <selectparameters>
        <asp:querystringparameter querystringfield="{VariableName}" name="someVariable" />
    </selectparameters>
</asp:sqldatasource>
```

You can find more on the latter on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad.aspx)

Comment: Hi, yes I understand the principle, and I think I can create the link on the ListView with no problem. But how do I make the FormView to pickup the querystring Id value and apply to the query?

Comment: @user441365 You will need to do this in code on your `Page_Load` event. Alternatively if you use data source, you can specify the parameters in the datasource parameter list.

Comment: @user441365 I have added some code samples to explain what I mean.

Comment: sorry, I implemented the second option and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually when passing details between forms i overide the form's constructor with a value that i can assign. What are you using to bind the information? Let me know if you need more info

If its asp.net you can send info as session state, or in query string etc